# add jquery tab dynamically from another javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery to create tabs. I put the javascript code in a separate file. tabset variable is used to reference the tab. Javascript has the following content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//add a tabset
var tabset = $("#tabset").tabs({
    /*add close button*/
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    /*cache tabs*/
    cache: true,
    /*immediately select a just added tab*/
    add: function(event, ui) {
        //alert(ui.panel.id);
        tabset.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
    }
});
```

I could add another tab with the statement below. This works fine if I call this statement from this javascript.

```
tabset.tabs('add', url, nameToCheck);
```

I would like to add a new tab to the tabset called #tabset from another javascript file where I could not use tabset variable because it is out of scope.

I try to use jquery selector to find tabset and call add function but the tab is not added. Please check the statement below:

```
$('#tabset').tabs('add', 'url', 'newTab');
```

My question is: how to add another tab to existing tabset from any javascript file? How to select an existing tabset and to call an add function?

Best regards,
Javanus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabset").tabs({
    tabTemplate: yourtabtemplate,
    cache: true,
    add: function(event, ui) {
        // Change 'tabset' to 'this'
        this.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
    }
});
```

And in the other JS file:

```
var tabset = $('#tabset');
tabset.tabs('add', url, nameToCheck);
```

Or simply:

```
$('#tabset').tabs('add', 'url', 'newTab');
```

**EDIT**: the problem is that you probably are adding your first file before your second file. So, `$('#tabset')` doesn't have tabs feature from JQueryUI and `$('#tabset').tabs('add')` is not working.

Switch the order like this:

file1.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabset").tabs({
    tabTemplate: yourtabtemplate,
    cache: true,
    add: function(event, ui) {
        // Change 'tabset' to 'this'
        this.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
    }
});
```

file2.js:

```
$('#tabset').tabs('add', 'url', 'newTab');
```

You index view:

```
<script src="scripts/file1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/file2.js"></script>
```

Check file order. Happy codding!

Comment: Hi, thank you for a quick response but this is not working. I have already put $('#tabset').tabs('add', 'url', 'newTab'); in my example. The problem is that this is not working. Any other solution? The problem is, that add is not working when it is referenced with $('#tabset_name').

Comment: @javanus Did you remove `var tabset = $('#tabset').tabs({...` from your file, and just write `$('#tabset').tabs({...` as I did?

Comment: @javanus I edit my own answer. I think that file order could be getting you in troubles.

Comment: Hi, Fran. I have developed a test case and I found out that $('#tabset').tabs('add', 'url', 'newTab') works fine but it does not work in my project. New tab is added only the first time when the user click on the menu item. I must find out where is the problem. Thank for your help. Regards, Javanus

Comment: I found out the reason for the problem with adding tabs. My application uses struts2-jquery-plugin. Tabs stop to work each time I add <sj:head jqueryui="true"/> to the jsp page. Adding tabs stop to work after the fist tab is added. Regards, Javanus

Comment: @javanus Great! Sometimes others plugin can interfere between themselves. Good job :)